# Calculating 3d points for spherical cap

Tags: graphics3d

Calculating 3d points for spherical cap, given radius for sphere and height of cap (h).

Answer (score 1):

```
h = 10; r = 2;

pts = RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, h}, r], 
   1000, {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {h, h + r}}];

Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, r], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]